# Creating a database of math questions and of answers and a front end for them

Tags: databases, python

Need some guidance on where to begin.  I am just learning python if it has any bearing.

I want to create a page on my site where users log in, choose multiple topics from a list, choose between levels of difficulty, choose whether or not to be timed, and then be presented with random multiple choice questions on the topics at the chosen level that I have created in advance.  They should be able to answer the questions and then be scored at the end if they chose to be timed (like an exam setting) or else be given the option to see the written solutions as they go which I have also created.  So they would see one question at a time.  If not timed, then they could choose to see the solution at any time; if timed, then they could skip the question or choose an answer and then when all of the questions have been skipped or answered would be scored.

I am imagine that I would put the questions and solutions in some kind of database, and then create some kind of interface with dropdown lists.  The idea is to create a practice space for students preparing for certain kinds of exams.

How do I create such a database of questions and of solutions?  Using SQL or mySQL (never used either).

And for the front end could that be done with python or simply html?

Comment: First, I find this question out of scope for CS.SE as we're not a programming site. Second, I think the question is way too broad for any SE site. SE works best for focused questions which have precise answers. With that being said, yes, you might use a database for this but perhaps a simpler file-based solution is also fine. There are many possibilities for the frontend, eg you could try Dash if you want a Python library or go directly for html, react or such. You probably need to understand the requirements better to make a decision.

Comment: (another [math@SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?)

Comment: @Juho Can you suggest a resource for me to learn how to do this project and how to decide whether a database or file-base is better?  There will eventually be thousands of questions and solutions if it matters.  This is a personal project, not a school assignment.  What do you mean by requirements?

Comment: @Juho What site do you think is appropriate for this question?

Comment: I think this is too open-ended for any SE site. Also, there's probably no single resource to walk you through this, that is, you will have to learn the bits and pieces and put it all together. Finally, the requirements for eg the user experience will dictate what you actually need, like for instance if you should use heavier tools like databases instead of plain files.

Comment: @Juho "the requirements for eg the user experience will dictate what you actually need, like for instance if you should use heavier tools like databases instead of plain files."  How can I assess that?  Should I hire some kind of a consultant?  Or if I wanted to build a simple prototype would I start with Dash, for example, and a file-base?

Comment: Only you know the answer to that: how robust, responsive, resilient etc need the system be? Build a rudimentary skeleton first in an agile manner.